# How do I invalidate a login session initialized in one servlet in another servlet with a href in between?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on a web app and I have to implement  a **login/logout** system. I have already implemented the login system(validating by verification through a database) in a controller servlet. Basically the most important aspect of my project is to keep  a **MVC approach**.
So here is the controller login servlet that I have implemented,

```
package com.cid_org.controller;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.cid_org.model.*;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginControllerServlet
 */

public class LoginControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public LoginControllerServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    /*Take the data submitted by the user though the login 
     * form(Remember the HTTP Post request ->HttpServletRequest request object*/
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    System.out.println(username + "aaa");
    System.out.println(pwd);
    Connection connection = (Connection)getServletContext().getAttribute("connection_context_param");

    LoginModelPOJO lmpojo = new LoginModelPOJO(username, pwd, connection);
    boolean isUserValidFlag = lmpojo.isValid();

    if(isUserValidFlag){
        /*Entering this block indicates the user has been validated and if the
         * user has been validated, we should start a session. But here is a
         * question, where exactly(at which point) should we say that user has 
         * logged in? -I guess when the user sends his/her our login info. 
         * for validation and right at the moment the info. gets validated,
         * we can say at this particular point in program he is IN. And this
         * is the precise point for a Login session to start. So remember 
         * at this point we are logged in*/

        /*Getting the session*/
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        RequestDispatcher view =request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/view_profile.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
    else{
        /*And obviously the unauthorized user will be redirected to the login page.*/
        response.sendRedirect("login.html");
    }

    }

}
```

And here is the view_profile.jsp,I  dispatch the request to,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Crime Investigation Department-User" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Criminal Investigation Department</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CrimeReportingSystem5/static/css/view_profile_page.css">
</head>

<body>

    <img src="css/images/logo/CID_Logo_1.png" alt="CID Logo">

    <nav id="navigation">
        <a id="link1" class="header_links" href="most_wanted.html">Most Wanted</a>
        <a id="link2" class="header_links" href="hotnews.html">Hot News</a>
        <a id="link3" class="header_links" href="report_crime.html">Report Crime</a>
        <a id="link4" class="header_links" href="login.html">Login</a>
        <a id="link5" class="header_links" href="about.html">About Us</a>
        <a id="link6" class="header_links" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        <a id="link7" class="header_links" href="safety_measures.html">Safety Measures</a>
    </nav>

    <%
        /*Remember we got to this page only after validation of the username
         *from the servlet ,point being the username has already been validated 
         *so all we got to do here is retrieve the username form the request
         *object and it.*/
        String username = request.getParameter("username");

        if(username == null){
            response.sendRedirect("/CrimeReportingSystem5/static/login.html");
        }
    %>
    <div id="login_page_border">
        <span id="welcome_username_text">Welcome <%=username%></span>
    <a href="/CrimeReportingSystem5/view/RetrieveComplaints.do" id="view_complaints_tab">View Complaints</a>
    <a href="/CrimeReportingSystem5/view/edit_profile.jsp" id="edit_profile_tab">Edit Profile</a>
    <a href="/CrimeReportingSystem5/view/Logout.do" id="logout_profile_tab">Logout</a>      
    <div id="profile_layout">

    </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**My problem:** I want to implement a **logout** system for which I already generated a session in Login servlet and I have decided to invalidate the session in another Logout servlet but there lies a link in between them(see the jsp) so the request sent will be a GET request to the servlet,how can I send session info. to the Logout servlet for the invalidation.
Btw, I have read another answer in which it was suggested to create a static Map variable and store JSESSIONID and session as map variable but even if I did that,how would I know which user clicked the logout link?
**Note:** I can't use **JavaScript or Jquery** for the solution cause I am yet to read them. Please provide a simple solution.

Comment: Indeed this question is duplicate but the other question had 0 answers so I asked it again in context of my project

Comment: set attribute to session store attribute to cookie use it by validating with cookie and finally invalidate it

Comment: @M.Sharma: Your comment doesn't make sense to me, please properly punctuate it.

Comment: refer [this](http://www.journaldev.com/1907/java-servlet-session-management-tutorial-with-examples-of-cookies-httpsession-and-url-rewriting). It maynot be the best implementation but it will give you a general idea of what to do

Comment: @M.Sharma: Well well well,didn't you see my requirements(in the heading of question)? I have a link between the 2 servlets -A LINK, the answer link you suggested provides a solution using forms and I don't want it

Comment: learn about url redirecting

Comment: @pulp_fiction: It doesn't matter that there is a link between your pages. M.Sharma's tutorial is really good. Read it carefully and try to understand how the servlet server handles sessions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see problems where no problems are.

It's quite easy to invalidate the current session inside a servlet:

```
// Check, if there is a session active. Avoid to create a new one.
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session != null) {
  session.invalidate();
}
```

It doesn't matter, if this code runs in a different servlet than where you created the session.

Internally the session is usually managed by a browser cookie. So when you create a new session the server sends a cookie to the browser associated to the domain. Then each subsequent request the browser transmits this cookie to your server. Your servlet server implementation (like Tomcat) then checks this cookie against the active sessions, so that your next `request.getSession()` returns the right session corresponding to the specific user.

Comment: Okay, but what if there are multiple logins simultaneously, now which session will be returned by request.getSession() as there should be multiple sessions for multiple users.The possibility is of any of the logged in user to logout at any moment

Comment: No, the servlet server does the hard work to associate the cookie to the right user. Each user's session is identified by a unique session id transferred via the session cookie. So the server knows on each following request, which was the original sesion of this user.

Comment: You can try it by yourself. Use two different browsers to login to your side (e.g. Chrome and Firefox). Don't use different tabs of the browser because of cookie sharing between tabs. The server will create a new session for each browser and any subsequent request will give you the right session back in `request.getSession()`.

Comment: Yeah I did check it and you are right all the hard work is done by the container.Thanks